# Convert this SQL Pivot Union to Linq - Pivot with custom labels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to add labels for each aggregate column. I made this SQL but now I'm trying to convert this into Linq. I can't figure it out and I tried many 'pivot' answers.

SQL

```
select * from (
    select 'Orders' as Label, UNIT, NUMBER_OF_ORDERS 
    from PS_TABLE1
    where TRANSACTION_DATE = trunc(sysdate)-1 and UNIT in ('NYC','BOS')
)
pivot (
    SUM(NUMBER_OF_ORDERS) 
    FOR ( UNIT) IN ('BOS' as BOS,'NYC' as NYC)
)
union
select * from (
    select  'Items' as Label, UNIT,NUMBER_OF_ITEMS 
    from PS_TABLE1
    where TRANSACTION_DATE = trunc(sysdate)-1 and UNIT in ('NYC','BOS')
)
pivot (
    SUM(NUMBER_OF_ITEMS) 
    FOR ( UNIT) IN ('BOS' as BOS,'NYC' as NYC)
)
```

Results:

```
LABEL |BOS|NYC
Items |601|416
Orders|94 |79
```

How would the model and the linq statement would look like? Do I need to use Dynamic Type?

Comment: Does Orders and Items have a relationship?

Comment: Not really. The only relationship is that they are in the same table.  They may be different datatypes actually like decimal and int. I would have to convert it so all have the same datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the easiest answer type to use is a `DataTable` which allows for dynamic column creation. I normally use a `Pivot` method that takes a `DataTable`, and convert any source into one on the fly, but a dedicated `Pivot` method for `IEnumerable<T>` is probably better.

First, you will need some extensions to use Reflection to collect property names and work with them:

```
public static class MemberInfoExt {
    public static Type GetMemberType(this MemberInfo member) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return mfi.FieldType;
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.PropertyType;
            case EventInfo mei:
                return mei.EventHandlerType;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be if type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or EventInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }

    public static object GetValue(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return mfi.GetValue(srcObject);
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.GetValue(srcObject);
            case MethodInfo mi:
                return mi.Invoke(srcObject, null);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or MethodInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }
}

public static class ObjectExt {
    public static object GetValue<T>(this T obj, string memberName) => obj.GetType().GetPropertyOrField(memberName).GetValue(obj);
    public static object GetValue<T>(this T obj, MemberInfo mi) => mi.GetValue(obj);
}

public static class TypeExt {
    public static List<MemberInfo> GetPropertiesOrFields(this Type t, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
        t.GetMembers(bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field || mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).ToList();

    public static MemberInfo GetPropertyOrField(this Type t, string memberName, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
        t.GetMember(memberName, bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field || mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).Single();
}
```

Then using these extension methods you can create a method to pivot an `IEnumerable<T>` using a summarize function:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    // Summarize and pivot IEnumerable<T>
    // Property (or field) OverColName values are new column names
    // Remaining property (or field) names are new row values for @RowLabelName
    // value for new @RowLabelName,col computed by applying SumFn to @RowLabelName values from row col
    // method assumes all non-OverColName properties (or fields) are of the same type
    public static DataTable PivotOverFor<TRow,TValue,TResult>(this IEnumerable<TRow> src, string OverColName, Func<IEnumerable<TValue>,TResult> SumFn, string RowLabelName = "Label") {
        var dtg = src.GroupBy(r => r.GetValue(OverColName).ToString()).ToList();

        var ans = new DataTable();
        ans.Columns.Add(RowLabelName, typeof(string));

        var newColDataType = typeof(TResult);
        var newColNames = dtg.Select(g => g.Key).OrderBy(s => s).ToList();
        foreach (var cn in newColNames)
            ans.Columns.Add(cn, newColDataType);

        var srcMI = typeof(TRow).GetPropertiesOrFields().Where(mi => mi.Name != OverColName);
        foreach (var mi in srcMI) {
            var nr = ans.NewRow();
            nr[RowLabelName] = mi.Name;
            foreach (var g in dtg) {
                nr[g.Key] = SumFn(g.Select(r => (TValue)r.GetValue(mi)));
            }
            ans.Rows.Add(nr);
        }

        return ans;
    }
}
```

Now you can just call the `PivotOverFor` extension method on your source data. I put in a `Select` to transform the source property names into the desired final names:

```
var ans = PS_Table1.Select(r => new { r.Unit, Orders = r.NumberOfOrders, Items = r.NumberOfItems })
                   .PivotOverFor("Unit", (Func<IEnumerable<int>, int>)Enumerable.Sum);
```

PS The cast of `Enumerable.Sum` picks the correct specific one needed, otherwise you'd have to create an unneeded lambda to set the data types.